# Why isn't /etc/skel/.kde being copied into new user directories?

Tags: linux, debian, kde

I'm building custom Debian images with both GNOME and KDE desktops. When I place `~/.config` in `/etc/skel/` to capture my GNOME settings (mainly a custom wallpaper) it gets copied into new user directories correctly. However, when I place `~/.kde` in `/etc/skel/` to capture my KDE settings, it does **not** get copied into new user directories.

Any idea if only certain directories in `/etc/skel/` get copied into new user directories? I'm thinking it's not a GNOME- or KDE-specific issue because I had also tried placing a `develop` directory with some source code I wanted everyone to have in `/etc/skel/` and it does **not** get copied on my GNOME image even when the `/etc/skel/.config` directory does get copied.

Answer (score 1):

**I know this is dated a bit (3 years), but in case and for other here it is.**

I found out that Kwallet (summary KDE password management system) is interferring with creation of content in /etc/skel/

The solution then is to :

- disable KWallet in Account Details > KDE Wallet (as of plasma 5.12.6)
- In case you're using LDAP, comment out lines mentionning kwallet in /etc/pam.d/sddm

Hope it helps.